# Marshal.Copy not copying over value

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport, intptr

I'm not very familiar with C# and I'm trying to use *'Marshal.Copy'* but it's not changing the value of the IntPtr that I'm using.

```
IntPtr ptr = InitPointer(width, height);

Marshal.Copy(inputIntArray, 0, ptr, width * height * 4);
```

Where InitPointer is defined as:

```
[DllImport(@"../../../../Debug/KernelApplier.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr InitPointer(int x, int y);
```

And in my kerneApplier.dll the function is written as:

```
int * inputBuffer;
int size;
int m_x, m_y;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int* InitPointer(int x, int y) {
    size = x*y * sizeof(cl_int3);
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    inputBuffer = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    return inputBuffer;
}
```

I'm using my watch window to monitor the values where:

- ptr.m_value = 0x0641c040
- inputIntArray[0] = 152
- 0x0641c040 = 104972352 //This does not change after the Marshal.Copy

Am I using Marshal.copy incorrectly or is there a problem passing the data from C++ to C#

Comment: Did you note that `104972352` is `0x641C040`? You cannot enter a number in the watch window, because it will ever be a number only

Comment: It's confusing when you say "copying the data from C++ to C#". Yes the pointer is allocated in the C++ code and passed to the C# code. But the data in the array is being passed from C# to C++. At least that's what I presume is happening.....

Comment: You are not changing the pointer, you are changing the memory it points to.  Use Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory1 and put "ptr" in the Address box, now you can see it.

Comment: David, thank you, I will clear up my question.
Hans & Thomas, thank you for telling me how to view what is stored in a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The `IntPtr` value does not change, but it's the address of the unmanaged memory so it is not expected to change.